# Nginx 301や404になってしまう

Tags: nginx

root直下のファイル以外が読み込まれない状況です。
`http://ドメイン/.well-known/acme-challenge`内にあるindex.htmlを表示させたいのですが、アクセスすると、404や301エラーになってしまいます。

単純に静的ページの読み込みなんですが、どのように設定すれば良いか解決策を教えていただけると助かります。
環境は、CentOS7でNginx 1.12.2です。

`curl -i`コマンドで確認すると、以下のように結果が変わっているのがわかりました。
[http://ドメイン/.well-known/acme-challenge](http://%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3/.well-known/acme-challenge)

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 20 May 2018 16:38:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://ドメイン/.well-known/acme-challenge

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

[http://ドメイン/.well-known/acme-challenge/](http://%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3/.well-known/acme-challenge/)

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 20 May 2018 16:38:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

[http://ドメイン/.well-known/acme-challenge/index.html](http://%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3/.well-known/acme-challenge/index.html)

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 20 May 2018 16:39:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

curl -i http://localhost:80/.well-known/acme-challenge/index.html

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Mon, 21 May 2018 14:27:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.12.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

nginx.confの設定は以下の通りです。
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/`以下に設定ファイルはありません。`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`のみです。

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    index    index.html index.htm index.php;

    server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  ドメイン;
      root /var/www/html;
    }

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;   

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
}
```

/etc/nginx/mime.types

```
types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}
```

Comment: `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` の下にファイルはありますか？

Comment: いえ、ありません。`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`のみです。

Comment: なぜか https にリダイレクトされてるようですが、設定上変なところは見受けられないので不可解ですね。ためしに サーバー上で localhost に対して curl を実行した結果と、`/etc/nginx/mime.types` の内容が気になりますね。

Comment: すみません、localhost に対して curl を実行をしたことがないのですが、質問欄にある実行コマンドで問題ないでしょうか？
実は以前、発行を行ったのですが、更新しなかったため削除処理を行い、今回新たに発行する次第です。
`mime.types`を質問欄に追加しました。

Comment: curlの実行結果を見ると、https のアドレスにリダイレクトされているのが見て取れます。しかしながら、設定ファイルにはリダイレクトの設定は存在せず、また、conf.d 配下に他の設定ファイルも無いということから、通信経路上の何かしらの問題ではないかと疑っています。ですので、サーバー上で localhost に対して curl を実行しますと、通信経路上の要因を排除出来るので 現象の切り分けとしてやってみてはどうかなと思った次第です。実行方法は、サーバーにログインした上で `curl -v http://localhost/.well-known/acme-challenge` と実行してみてください。

Comment: お名前.comなど確認したところ、DNS設定が間違っていました。無事に証明書が取得できました。ご回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。DNSの設定に問題がありました。

Comment: お疲れ様でした。もし可能であれば、同じような問題に遭遇された方のために、どのような問題があったのかを追記して下さいませんか？

Answer (score 0):

301 redirectが起きるのは、そうなるようnginx.confファイルに書いたからです。

301 redirectのリダイレクトフラグは、"permanent"ですから、nginx.confでpermanentを含む行を探して削除（もしくはコメントアウト）してnginxを再起動すれば、301 redirectが起きなくなるはずです。

301 redirectの情報は、Webブラウザ側でキャッシュされます（指定したURLで301が返ってくると、次回以降は指定されたURLではなく、redirect先(現状では404が返ってくる)に直にアクセスするようになります。）
そのため、動作確認の前にWebブラウザのキャッシュを削除してください。

＝＝＝
使っていらしゃる nginx.confの内容と、どのようなリダイレクトがしたいのかを質問に追記すると、nginx.confの修正方法をアドバイスしてもらえると思います。

Comment: 301 redirect関連の記述は書いていません。質問欄のnginx.confのみです。conf.d以下に設定ファイルはありません。
キャッシュを削除しましたが、ダメでした。

.well-known/acme-challenge内にあるindex.htmlが表示したいです。